# Call Route URL sending Parameters CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

Hello im working with code igniter  and I try to send parameters from url into view to controller

My Controller

```
public function mainView($num=null) {
        $this->load->view('header');



        // $data = array('foo[' => 'Hello', 'bar' => 'world');
        if (!isset($_SESSION[$this::jsondevices])) {
            var_dump("Descargo");

            $_SESSION[$this::jsondevices] = $this->restlib->consumirDominiosDeMoca($this->restmodel->modelUserDevices());
            $_SESSION[$this::jsontags] = $this->restlib->consumirDominiosDeMoca($this->restmodel->modelTagsMoca());
        }
        var_dump("No descargo");
        $data = $this->piemodel->mainValues($this, $_SESSION[$this::jsondevices], $_SESSION[$this::jsontags]);

        $this->load->view('user/login/vistachart', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
```

My js

```
  window.location.href = "<?= base_url('home2/$1')?>";
```

And my route

```
$route['home2/(:num)'] = 'user/mainView/$1';
```

And the result

> 404 Page Not Found

But I try with `$route['home']       = 'user/mainView';`
Work's
What Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send your parameter like this in js:

```
 window.location.href = "<?= base_url('home2/1')?>";
```

it redirects to `user/mainView/1` where `1` is parameter.

Also don't forget to load `url` helper in `application/config/autoload.php`.

Comment: glad to help you.best of luck.

Comment: the url charge but param is null , ever

Comment: try using `public function mainView($num=FALSE)`.

Comment: For more see here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html hope you will get something new.